# WPF ComboBox Subclass can't find Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a subclass of a Combobox, with a custom style. It is working so far, but the designer of visual studio is unable to show the design view of my combobox.

Error message:
The element "[MyComboBox]" could not be displayed because of a problem with MyResourceLib.Controls.MyComboBox:
Cannot create an instance of "MyComboBox"

Here is a minimal example of my ComboBox:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyResourceLib.Controls
{
    public partial class MyComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        public MyComboBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox
    x:Class="MyResourceLib.Controls.MyComboBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyResourceLib.Controls"
    Style="{StaticResource StyleComboBox}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/ComboBoxes.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

In Addition to this, i get an error when using the combobox element:

Cannot find resource named "StyleComboBox". Resource names are case sensitive.

Ironically it uses the Style at runtime...

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this wrong. `MyComboBox` should be a plain class without any XAML file:

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    static MyComboBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyComboBox),
            new System.Windows.FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyComboBox)));
    }

    public MyComboBox()
    {

    }
}
```

You then define the default style of your custom control in a `ResourceDictionary` called `Generic.xaml` located in a folder called `Themes` at the root of your project:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/ComboBoxes.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style TargetType="local:MyComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource YourComboBoxStyle}">
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

These names are by convention and this is how you define a default style for a custom control. Do again - do right.